# How to optimize a cholesky solution

Tags: c, numpy, optimization

I want to solve a matrix equation A*x=B using a cholesky solution, where A can be decomposed into L and L^T to instead solve the equation L(L^T * x)=B. I first solve L*y = B using forward substitution and then L^T * x=y using backwards substitution. Both A and B are dense matrices and A is obviously symmetric. I want to write this in C, and I compare it to a python implementation using linalg.cho_solve and linalg.cho_factor. The problem is that my C code is considerably slower than the python implementation. How can I optimize my C code so it runs faster?

First I do a cholesky decomposition:

```
double* cholesky_factor(double* matrix, size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols) {
    
    // Timer
    clock_t tik, tok;
    double time_taken;
    tik = clock();

    double* L = (double*)calloc(n_rows * n_cols, sizeof(double));
        if (L == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: calloc failed to allocate memory\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    printf("start");

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n_rows; i++){
        for (size_t j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            double sum = 0;
            for (size_t k = 0; k < j; k++)
            {
                sum += L[i * n_cols + k] * L[j * n_cols + k];
            }
            
            if (i == j) {
                L[i * n_cols + i] = sqrt(matrix[i * n_cols + i] - sum);
            } else {
                L[i * n_cols + j] = (1.0 / L[j * n_cols + j]) * (matrix[i * n_cols + j] - sum);
            }
        }
    }
        
    tok = clock();
    time_taken = (double)(tok - tik) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("C timer, Time taken for cholesky_factor: %f seconds\n", time_taken);

    return L;
}
```

The following code implementation gives me a solution from the cholesky factors:

```
void transpose(int n_rows, int n_cols, const double* matrix, double* tran) {

    for (int i = 0; i < n_rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n_cols; j++) {
            tran[j * n_rows + i] = matrix[i * n_cols + j];
        }
    }
}

double* forward_substitusion(const double* L, const double* B, size_t n_rows,size_t n_cols){
    double* Y = (double*)calloc(n_rows * n_cols, sizeof(double));
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_rows; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n_cols; j++) {
            double sum = 0;
            for (size_t k = 0; k < n_rows; k++) {
                sum += L[i*n_rows + k] * Y[k*n_rows + j];
            }
            Y[i*n_rows + j] = (B[i*n_rows + j] - sum) / L[i*n_rows + i];
        }
    }

    return Y;
}

double* backwards_substitution(const double* U, const double* y, size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols) {
    double* X = (double*)calloc(n_rows * n_cols, sizeof(double));

    for (int i = n_rows - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = n_cols - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            double sum = 0;
            for (size_t k = 0; k < n_rows; k++) {
                sum += U[i * n_rows + k] * X[k * n_cols + j];
            }
            X[i * n_cols + j] = (y[i * n_cols + j] - sum) / U[i * n_rows + i];
        }
    }

    return X;
}

double* cholsky_solver(const double* L, const double* B, size_t n_rows, size_t n_cols){
    
    // Timer
    clock_t tik, tok;
    double time_taken;
    tik = clock();

    double* L_T= (double*) calloc(n_rows*n_cols,sizeof(double));

    transpose(n_rows, n_cols, L, L_T);
    
    double* Y = forward_substitusion(L,B,n_rows, n_cols);

    double* X = backwards_substitution(L_T,Y,n_rows, n_cols);
    free(Y);

    tok = clock();
    time_taken = (double)(tok - tik) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("C timer, Time taken for cholsky_solver: %f seconds\n", time_taken);
    
    return X;
}
```

Then the code in python just uses inalg.cho_solve and linalg.cho_factor from numpy.

Comment: by "python solution" do you mean `numpy` library?

Comment: btw. replace `double* Y = (double*)calloc(n_rows * n_cols, sizeof(double));` with `double *Y = calloc(n_rows * n_cols, sizeof *Y);` it is shorter and there is no need to repeat `double` 3 times.

Comment: The Wikipedia page on this topic states that you can do a LDL* variation of the algorithm which doesn't require the calculation of square roots. I suspect that could in part be why yours is slower.

Comment: @tstanisl yes with python solution I meant the numpy libery, using it's linalg.cho_solve and linalg.cho_factor functions

Comment: It is worth noting, that numpy will be using LAPACK/BLAS for matrix decompositions, which are libraries written in FORTRAN and have been optimised for 30 odd years. Your timings will always be worse as long as the python overhead is small.